# dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) method is not called in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-keypad

In my *Android* app there is only 1 `Activity` and a bunchs of java classes.

I need to use `Remote Control` (arrow keys like DPAD) to go through all items not touch. So I tried to use `onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` method. But this method just works in `Activity` and in other files I use `dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)` method.

The problem is that in some files this method is not called at all.
Does any body know that this method is useful for my app or not and also why this method is not called in some files?

```
public Music_app(final Context context) {
    super(context);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    setLayoutParams(lp);
    this.context=context; 
    LayoutInflater inflater = 
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    xmlLayout_layer1 = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_music, null);
    xmlLayout_layer1.setLayoutParams(lp);
    addView(xmlLayout_layer1);

    TextView album_btn = (TextView) xmlLayout_layer1.findViewById(R.id.music_album);
    TextView singer_btn = (TextView) xmlLayout_layer1.findViewById(R.id.music_singer);
    TextView year_btn = (TextView) xmlLayout_layer1.findViewById(R.id.music_year);
    TextView genre_btn = (TextView) xmlLayout_layer1.findViewById(R.id.music_genre);        

    album_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    levelTwoList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) SoapCommand.invokeMethod(SoapCommand.LIST_MUSIC_SECOND_LEVEL,
                            SoapCommand.KEY_MUSIC_LEVEL_2,
                            SoapCommand.KEY_LANGUAGE,
                            Integer.toString(1),
                            LocalDatabase.language);
                    Log.e("levelTwoList ",""+levelTwoList );
                    first_level_path = context.getString(R.string.album);
                    first_level_type = 1;
                    goToSecondLevel(1);
                } 
            });
            t.start();
        }
    });     
}


@Override 
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    Log.e("Umd", "Music ");

    if (event.getAction()!=KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){
        switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:{
                Log.e("FF1", "RIGHT");
                return true; 
            }
        }
    }

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Please put your source code.

Comment: My code has many lines. So I tried to eliminate some lines which are not important about this issue.